# Linear approximation calculation.

Tags: calculus

Here is my question:

> Find the linearization $L(x)$ of the function at `a`.

$$f(x) = \sin{x}, a = \frac{\pi}{6}.$$

So we need $f(a)$, $f'(a)$ and $(x - a)$

So:

$$ f'(x) = \cos{x}$$
$$ f'\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$$

so the linearization is:

$$ L(x) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(x-a)$$

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Correct?(: Not even allowed to write such short answers

Comment: So close. Why’d you leave an $a$ in the final expression?

Comment: ohhhhhhh I should replace the a with the value a, I see

Answer (score 1):

[That is indeed 100% totally correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BSin%5Bx%5D,%7Bx,Pi%2F6,1%7D%5D).